# Materializecss how to get label on left side of input

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I have a project with materializecss, and I would like to put the `label` when `class="active"` (which is always) to the left of the input field. How do I move the label to the left, while shrinking the input field relatively so it all fits nicely in the column?

[Here is my jsfiddle of the scenario](https://jsfiddle.net/k0h30qx6/)

Comment: the label by default goes on top of the input box. What you could do instead is have some text before the input box instead of the label.

Comment: really smart idea. i will give that a try

Comment: I have also added an answer that you might find of use.

Comment: thanks! i think the text option works better

Comment: @Alastair how would remove the labels affect accessibility?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the inline class http://materializecss.com/forms.html

```
<div class="row">
 <form class="col s12">
  <div class="row">    
   <div class="col s12">
     First Name:
     <div class="input-field inline">
       <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate square-box align-right">
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Alastair said in the comments under the question, I simply removed the labels altogether, and just used a `<p></p>` in its own `div`, and placed that div in a `col` to the left of the `input`